# update state inside react lifecycle not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so the initial problem like this, I have a component select the language that is imported into the login component, from the language component when the onChange event I hit an API then the response from the API I put into local storage, when I retrieve data from local storage to be called in login component and entered into the login component state, the data is not updated as local storage, but if the local storage data is successfully updated, how to update the state in the lifecycle react?

this is state from component login

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      getDataLocal:[]
    }
  }
```

and I want get data from localstorage and update to state

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    //set state and get data from localstorage
    this.setState({
      getDataLocal:JSON.parse(this.props.resGet('toLocalPages')),
      loading:false
    })
  }
```

unsuccessfully updated and still contains an empty array

```
render() {
    const { loading,getDataLocal} = this.state

    //getDataLocal unsuccessfully updated and still contains an empty array
    console.log(getDataLocal)

    if(this.state.redirect){
      return <Redirect to='/home' />
    }
    //untuk menghandle data di localstorage
    if(this.props.resGet('data')){
      return <Redirect to='/home' />
    }

    if(loading){
      return(
        <p>loading</p>
      )
    }else{
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Container>
            <Padding />
              <Row>
                <Col md={{ span: 6, offset: 3 }} className='mx-auto'> 
                <Card>
                  <CardContent>
                    <Row>
                      <Col xs={12}>
                        <h3><b>{getDataLocal.page_login.title}</b></h3>
                        <p><b>{getDataLocal.page_login.subtitle}</b></p>
                        <br />
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                      <SelectLanguage />
                      <Form.Group controlId='formBasicEmail'>
                        <Form.Label><b>{getDataLocal.page_login.label1}</b></Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type='email' name='MEMBER_EMAIL' placeholder={getDataLocal.page_login.placeholder_label1} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                      </Form.Group>
                      <Form.Group controlId='formBasicPassword'>
                        <Form.Label><b>{getDataLocal.page_login.label2}</b></Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type='password' name='MEMBER_PASSWORD' placeholder={getDataLocal.page_login.placeholder_label2} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                      </Form.Group>
                      <p className='text-muted float-right'><b>{getDataLocal.page_login.forgot_password}</b></p>
                        <Button type='submit' variant='warning' className='text-white' size='md' block >{getDataLocal.page_login.button}</Button>
                    </Form>
                    <br/>
                    <p className='text-muted text-center'><b>Or</b></p>
                    <p className='text-primary text-center'><b><i className='fa fa-facebook-official' aria-hidden='true'></i>&nbsp;{getDataLocal.page_login.link_login}</b></p>
                    <br />
                    <p className='text-muted text-center'><b>{getDataLocal.page_login.text2}&nbsp;<Link to='/register'><span className='text-warning'>{getDataLocal.page_login.link_register}</span></Link></b></p>
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you getting your data console.log( JSON.parse(this.props.resGet('toLocalPages'))) before setState in componentDidMount ?

Comment: what does `this.props.resGet('toLocalPages')` do? because if it's calling an API I'm guessing that react doesn't wait for it to resolve before it sets the state. If you want to consume an API I would recommend looking at redux + redux-saga or some alternative.

Comment: Does it work in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: @PrakashKarena

I tried console.log (JSON.parse (this.props.resGet ('toLocalPages))) in the Lifecycle componentWillMount (), the data is called

Comment: @vhflat

this is a hoc that contains save, retrieve, delete data to localstorage

Comment: @AlexJolig this work but 
when I setState in componentDidMount, the data doesn't match the local storage location

Answer (score 0):

You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition. 
Note-
`componentDidUpdate()` will not be invoked if `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns false.

- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 0):

Two things, first you can't call [`componentDidUpdate`](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) directly, you have to check if the `props` or the `state` of the component change in order to perform some action, second, you're trying to assign a state `loading` that you didn't define in the first place, you do something like this:

```
state = {
  getDataLocal: [],
  loading: false
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { resGet } = this.props;

  if (prevProps.resGet('toLocalPages') !== resGet('toLocalPages')) {
    // Set state and get data from localstorage
    this.setState({
      getDataLocal: JSON.parse(resGet('toLocalPages')),
      loading: false
    })
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MuhamadRahmatSetiawan What kind of examples do you mean? What I mean was that `componentDidUpdate` can't be called directly because then, every time something updates in your component you'll be calling `setState` and the app will crash for sure.

Comment: so what do you think is the solution? Can you give specific examples? I'm still new to react

Comment: actually I mean this, I take data from local storage but the data changes because it is sent from another component, I take the data in local storage and display it in other components as well

Comment: @MuhamadRahmatSetiawan The solution will be to look for a `prop` or `state` in which you want to check the change, and after that change, you could update the variable throw the `componentDidUpdate` function. I mean you could assing a `state` equal to the value of your `localStorage` and when this change, update the `state`;

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that changing props does not call render. Seems like `getDerivedStateFromProps` would help you, as it helped me in same situations before.

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return{
      getDataLocal:JSON.parse(this.props.resGet('toLocalPages'))
    };
  }
```

Just try it and let me know if it works.